# CoffeeScript renders the submit action twice even though the code only submits it once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm following through with Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and section 11.5 teaches how to make images clickable. I followed through with the lessons and below is my store.js.coffee

```
$(document).on "ready page:change", ->
  $('.store .entry > img').click ->
    $(this).parent().find(':submit').click()
```

The above will allow me to click on pictures on my store page to add specific items to the cart, but it will "click" it twice, therefore adding two items to the cart instead of only one. The regular "add to cart" button works perfectly, so I am not quite sure where the problem is.

I am thinking that the above code isn't enough to pinpoint the problem, but I don't know which other sections of the code to post, so please let me know if you need additional information. Thanks!

Comment: How many times does your `$(document).on "ready page:change"` get triggered? Two times perhaps? One for the `'ready'` and again for the `'page:change'`?

Comment: @muistooshort yes! I got rid of ready and it now works. Do you know why that is? because the book says to use ready page:change

Comment: `page:change` is for Turbolinks, `ready` is the usual "page loaded and ready to go" event. Maybe try adding the jquery.turbolinks gem and just use `ready`, that gem hides the Turbolinks nonsense so that standard document-ready hooks are enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is on the first line of the script.

You need to separate the elements **ready** and **page:change**  with a coma.

Try it like this:

```
$(document).on "ready, page:change", ->
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `click` is probably triggering another click action on `.store`, `.entry`, or `img`. The fix would be to prevent the click's default action.

Try using this:

```
$(document).on "ready page:change", ->
  $('.store .entry > img').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).parent().find(':submit').click()
```

Comment: I implemented your code and it still adds two items to the cart

Answer (score 0):

The full code segment with the comma from vinibol12 is:

```
$(document).on "ready, page:change", ->
    $('.store .entry > img').click ->
        $(this).parent().find(':submit').click()
```

I confirm that this fixed the double submit issue for me in agile-web-development-with-rails-4_p2_0 section 11.5